# 万引き etymology. Why does 万引き mean shoplifting

Tags: kanji

I have just watched the Japanese "Shoplifter" movie and wonder why 万引きmeans shoplifting.

Comment: 「泥棒」もなんでやねんって思いますよね・・ muddy stick?

Comment: Wikipedia says https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%87%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D

Answer (score 2):

[引く](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%B0%FA%A4%AF) can mean to take something, in the sense of "pluck something", and 万 is often used to mean "a lot" in words like [万事【ばんじ】](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%CB%FC%BB%F6) (everything) or [万屋【よろずや】](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%CB%FC%B2%B0) (jack of all trades), so I thought it was a self explanatory word, "takes anything".

Edit: After seeing the above comment by Yuichi Tam, according to Japanese Wikipedia my pat explanation is all wrong:

語源

江戸時代から使われている語であり、語源の由来としては、

1. 商品を間引いて盗む「間引き」が変化して、万引き（万は当て字）になったとする説
2. 「間」に「運」の意味もあるためそれぞれを結合し、運を狙って引き抜くという意味で「まんびき」になったとする説
3. タイミング（間）を見計らって盗むことから
4. 一度やると癖になり万回繰り返すから

といった説があるが、1の説が有力であるとしている。

So basically it was originally "[mabiki](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%A4%DE%A4%D3%A4%AD)" (thinning plants) but someone used the "man" kanji on top of that.